# Select-Object cmdlet with -First parameter seems to disable Write-Output

Tags: powershell

I am using the following command to get the most recent ChangesetId for a given solution folder in TFS:

```
$SolutionServerFolder = "$/MyTfsProject/SupportBranch/MySolution"

$ChangesetId = Get-TfsItemHistory -HistoryItem $SolutionServerFolder -Recurse | Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty ChangesetId 

Write-Output "ChangesetId: $ChangesetId"
```

For some reason if I use the -First 1 option in my call to the Select-Object cmdlet the Write-Ouput call that follows does not print anything. I see the implicit output from the assignment of the variable but not the expected text: ChangesetId: 12345.

If I exclude the -First 1 and use -StopAfter 1 on the Get-TfsItemHistory cmdlet instead then it works as I expect:

```
$SolutionServerFolder = "$/MyTfsProject/SupportBranch/MySolution"

$ChangesetId = Get-TfsItemHistory -HistoryItem $SolutionServerFolder -Recurse -Stopafter 1 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ChangesetId 

Write-Output "ChangesetId: $ChangesetId"
```

I don't think that this has anything to do with the TFS cmdlets. I just happen to be working on that. It appears to be a Powershell syntax issue I don't understand.

Does anyone know the reason for this interaction between Select-Object with -First and Write-Output?

Regards,

Matthew MacFarland